# Use the Recursion Theorem to prove a function is equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

Given the Recursion Theorem:

For any set $A$, $a \in A$, and function $f: A \times  \mathbb{N} 
 \rightarrow A,\;$ there is a unique function $F:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ such that...

(i) $F(1)=a$, and

(ii) $F(n+1) = f(F(n),n)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Prove that is the function $F$ is as in the statement of the Recursion Theorem, then it is unique. That ism if $G:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ were another function satisfying (i) and (ii) in the statement of the theorem, then $F=G$.

Use induction...

Where do I begin here?

Comment: This is an induction proof, so you begin at the beginning: prove that $F(1)=G(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

This can (and probably should) be done by induction.

- $F(1)=G(1)=a$.
- Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and suppose that $F(n)=G(n)$. Then$$F(n+1)=f\bigl(F(n),n\bigr)=f\bigl(G(n),n\bigr)=G(n+1).$$